# Azure Logic App Http Get Action to Azure Maps Weather API body is missing

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-maps

I'm trying to create some Logic Apps to get weather information using the Azure Maps Weather API. I've got this working in my Asp.Net Core App. I can also make the call using Postman. For whatever reason, I can not get the body output using the Http Get Action in a Logic App.

Http Get Action

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http

Daily Forecast API call

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/weather/get-daily-forecast

HTTP Get Action configured (I've tried adding Accept application/JSON & Content-Type application/JSON as Headers along with query string parameters as queries etc..)

[image]

Raw output from Logic App run triggered manually

```
{
    "headers": {},
    "statusCode": "OK"
}
```

This works just fine in Postman.

https://atlas.microsoft.com/weather/forecast/daily/json?api-version=1.0&query=62.6490341%2C30.0734812&duration=5&subscription-key=AZUREMAPSAPIKEY

I created my first Logic App over 7 years ago. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is so difficult. :(

**UPDATE:** This API call from an HTTP Get Action works just fine.

https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick response @SwethaKandikonda-MT. I created a new Workflow and it's working just fine. I have no idea why it doesn't / didn't work in the first Workflow I created.

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from our end we observed that you are missing to add the AZUREMAPSAPIKEY. After adding the Azure maps Subscription primary key in place of AZUREMAPSAPIKEY we could able to retrieve the response.

Here is the screenshot for your reference
[image]

[image]